# Fuente Google no se visualiza en dispositivos móviles

Tags: css, css3, google-fonts

Tengo esta fuente que se ve perfectamente en el navegador de escritorio, pero cuando reviso en el móvil me aparece otra fuente diferente. ¿Tienen alguna idea de qué sucede?

Son son 2 parrafos, el primero lleva esta fuente

```
  font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
```

el segundo

```
font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
```

`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Questrial" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amatica+SC:700" rel="stylesheet">`

el segundo parrafo mantiene la fuente perfectamente, el primero al revisarlo en un telefono se cambia de fuente.

https://www.liderlogo.com/descuentos/

esta es la pagina del problema, es en la primera seccion , donde dice HOLA

Comment: Puedes agregar el codigo css que tienes para esas fuentes?, especificamente el `@font-face`

Comment: <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Questrial" rel="stylesheet">
 estoy trabajando en wordpress, como dije funciona perfectamente, solo que cuando voy a revisar la version movil no aparece la fuente, solo pasa con esa :c

Comment: Gracias por la edición @Michel. Debería funcionar así, por lo que necesitamos ver más de tu código. La idea es que todas las preguntas tengan un [mcve]... Tenemos que poder hacernos una idea de cómo es toda tu página (eliminale todo lo que no sea relevante)

Comment: Mira los headers que se incluye en mobile, normalmente los templates que compras traen un apartado para css mobile y otro para desktop

Comment: Editado nuevamente con mayor informacion

Comment: @MichelNovellino te he actualizado la respuesta, tienes un problema de css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes un problema con el CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) and (min-device-width: 320px)
(index):1
.hola>p>span {
    font-size: 400% !important;
    margin-left: -30%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    font-weight: bold !important;
    font-family: 'Questrial',sans-serif !important;
```

Te esta cambiando el estilo en resoluciones bajas.

---

Es importante añadir la fuente primero:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Questrial" rel="stylesheet">
```

O si lo haces por css:

```
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Questrial');
</style>
```

Asegúrate que una de estas dos lineas las tienes bien incluidas.

Luego ya puedes usar:

```
font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
```

Edito: Como dice Mariano en los comentarios, la etiqueta para importar la fuente tiene que ir en el head, antes de importar el CSS donde pones font-family.